# Diophantine Quintuple?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have come across the following set of numbers: $\{1, 3, 8, 120\}$

These are positive integers where the product of any two of the numbers equal to a number that is one less than a square number. (e.g. $1 \times 3$ = $3$, which is $1$ less than $4$, $2^2$; and $3 \times 8$ = $24$, which is $1$ less than $25$, $5^2$)

Is it possible to add another number to the list so that the product of any two numbers in the set will still equal to one less than a perfect square?

I have tried to prime factorise the already existing numbers in the list, but that got me nowhere (at least for now.)

Adding 0 to the list works, but it is a really trivial answer and I was wondering if there are any more numbers that can be added to the list.

A proof would be nice, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [OEIS A192629](http://oeis.org/A192629) it is stated that four integers is the maximum, but you can add $\frac {777480}{8288641}$.  You can multiply it by any number in the set, add one, and get a square rational number.  No further extension is known

Comment: A _quadruple_ with a special constraint can be extended to a rational _sextuple_. Kindly see [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1690931/4781) below.

Answer (score 9):

Andrej Dujella is the world expert on diophantine quintuples. Start reading [here](http://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~duje/intro.html). The conjecture is that there aren't any (not just that there's no 5th number after 1, 3,  8, 120, but that there's no set of 5 distinct positive integers with each product of two being one less than a square).

Answer (score 3):

(*This is an old question, but updates were found for the rational case by Dujella et al in $2015$*.)

> **I. Sextuple**

Given a ***quadruple*** {$a,b,c,d$}, if they satisfy an additional constraint, then it can be extended to a rational ***sextuple*** {$a,b,c,d,e,f$}. Let,

$$ab+1,\;ac+1,\;ad+1 = r_1^2,\; r_2^2,\; r_3^2\tag1$$

$$bc+1,\;bd+1,\;cd+1 = r_4^2,\; r_5^2,\; r_6^2\tag2$$

If also,

$$(abcd)^2-6abcd+2(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)-(a+b+c+d)^2-3=r_7^2\tag3$$

then one can find ***two more*** rationals {$e,f$},

$$e=\frac{1}{a}\Big(\frac{(r_1 r_2 r_3+a\, r_4 r_5 r_6)^2}{(abcd-1)^2}-1\Big)$$

$$f=\frac{1}{a}\Big(\frac{(r_1 r_2 r_3-a\, r_4 r_5 r_6)^2}{(abcd-1)^2}-1\Big)$$

such that the product of any two members of the sextuple {$a,b,c,d,e,f$} plus one is a square.

> **II. Example**

$$a,b,c,d = \frac{5}{4},\;\frac{5}{36},\;\frac{32}{9},\;\frac{189}{4}$$

Using the formulas, we get,

$$e,f = \frac{3213}{676},\;\frac{665}{1521}$$

> **III. Remarks**

1. The eq $(3)$ in fact has a parametric solution discussed in Dujella's [website](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~duje/ratio.html),

$$a = \frac{18t(t^2-1)}{(t^2-6t+1)(t^2+6t+1)}$$

$$b = \frac{(t - 1)(t^2 + 6t + 1)^2}{6t(t + 1)(t^2 - 6t + 1)}$$

$$c = \frac{(t + 1)(t^2 - 6t + 1)^2}{6t(t - 1)(t^2 + 6t + 1)}$$

$$d = \frac{r_3^2-1}{a}$$

Using an *elliptic curve*, appropriate values of $r_3$ will make all of $(2)$ also as squares. This implies there is an infinite number of sextuples which contain fixed $a,b,c$.

2. However, if $(a + b - c - d)^2 = 4(a b + 1)(c d + 1)$, then one of $e,f$ will be zero, hence will only yield a quintuple.

Comment: See also this [MO post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/233367/generalizing-a-pattern-for-the-diophantine-m-tuples-problem).