# Find a parametric formula to $n=(a^2+1)(b^2+1)$ in three distinct ways

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, parametric

I mentioned that the number $4420$ is expressible in the form $(a^2+1)(b^2+1)$ (where $a,b$ are positive integers) in three distinct ways,here is a list of these numbers:
$$4420=(1^2+1)(47^2+1)=(3^2+1)(21^2+1)=(5^2+1)(13^2+1)$$
$$26650=(2^2+1)(73^2+1)=(5^2+1)(32^2+1)=(9^2+1)(18^2+1)$$
$$……$$
$$16567585450=(13^2+1)(9872^2+1)=(47^2+1)(2738^2+1)=(278^2+1)(463^2+1)$$

I think about this problem from here:[A question on elementary number theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384006/a-question-on-elementary-number-theory)

Here is a relative problem ：http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath275.htm

So I wonder are there some parametric formulas for sets of these numbers(or at least for part of them)?Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a family of solutions:
$$
m_0=-1,m_1=5,m_{k+2}=38m_{k+1}-m_k \\
c_0=1,c_1=1,c_{k+2}=38c_{k+1}-c_k \\
a_k = 4m_k+c_k+\frac{2(m_k^2+1)}{c_k} \\
b_k = a_km_k-m_k^2-1 \\
n_k = a_k^2+b_k^2
$$
So for example
$$
n_1=120250=(68^2+1)(5^2+1)=(57^2+1)(6^2+1)=(43^2+1)(8^2+1)\\
n_3=505723158638933050=(98048^2+1)(7253^2+1)=(82137^2+1)(8658^2+1)=(62011^2+1)(11468^2+1)
$$

To arrive at this I started by observing that
$$
n = (x^2+1)(y^2+1)=(x+i)(x-i)(y+i)(y-i)
$$
where $i^2=-1$. Then first multiplying $(x+i)(y+i)$
$$
n = (xy-1+(x+y)i)(xy-1-(x+y)i) = (xy-1)^2+(x+y)^2
$$
or first multiplying $(x+i)(y-i)$
$$
n = (xy+1+(y-x)i)(xy+1-(y-x)i) = (xy+1)^2+(y-x)^2
$$
so letting $b=xy-1$ we have
$$
n=b^2+a^2=(b+2)^2+(a-2m)^2
$$
and given $b$ such that we can write $n$ this way we can reverse the procedure to find $x$ and $y$. Furthermore if we can write
$$
n=b^2+a^2=(b+2)^2+(a-2m)^2=(b+4)^2+(a-2m_2)^2=(b+6)^2+(a-2m_3)^2
$$
then we have at least three such representations pairing $b,b+2,b+4$ with $b+2,b+4,b+6$ respectively.
$$
b^2+a^2=(b+2)^2+(a-2m)^2 \implies b=am-m^2-1 \\
b^2+a^2=(b+4)^2+(a-2m_2)^2 \implies 2b=am_2-m_2^2-4 \\
b^2+a^2=(b+6)^2+(a-2m_3)^2 \implies 3b=am_3-m_3^2-9
$$
combining the first two gives
$$
a(m_2-2m)=m_2^2-2m^2+2
$$
Letting $m_2=2m+1$ immediately gives a family of numbers with two representations.
More generally let $m_2=2m+c$, then 
$$
ac = (2m+c)^2-2m^2+2 \\
a = c+4m+\frac{2m^2+2}{c}
$$
Combining the expressions for $b$ and $3b$ above we get
$$
m_3^2-am_3+6-3m^2+3ma=0
$$
For $m_3$ to be an integer we must have the discriminant be the square of an integer
$$
d^2 = a^2-12(2+ma-m^2)
$$
From here I didn't think of a good way to proceed, so using computer search for $(m,c)$ that give integers for $a$ and $d$ I found the first three solutions $(m,c)=(5,1),(191,37),(7253,1405)$ and came up with the recursion given at the top more-or-less by inspection. It remains to show that successive values for $m_k,c_k$ always result in $a_k$ and $d$ being integers, but I am confident that this is a straightforward exercise in induction and leave it to the interested reader.