# Find integers $(w, x, y, z)$ such that the product of each two of them minus 1 is square.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

In the case of $(5, 442, 541)$, the product of each  two of them minus 1 is a square:
$$5 \times 442 - 1 = 47^2, 5 \times 541 - 1 = 52^2, 442\times541 - 1 = 489^2$$

What are the integer-solutions $(w, x, y, z)$ for the case of four numbers, i.e.
$$w x - 1 = a^2, w y - 1 = b^2, w  z - 1 = c^2$$
$$x y - 1 = d^2, x  z - 1 = e^2, y z - 1 = f^2$$
where $a, b, c, d, e, f$ are integers?

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1184227_the_system_is_an_arithmetic_progression   http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1183749_system_with_permutations

Comment: I TeX'ed it and edited heavily for clarification; if this is in conflict with your intentions, feel free to use the roll-back feature if you click on the "edited" link under your post. Cheers.

Comment: @individ My question is in the case of T = -1. Unfortunately, T % 3 ≠　0.

Comment: @Manyama: W.Jagy has given an answer. However, if you are interested, if you have three integers $a,b,c$ such that, $$ab-1 =x^2\\ ac-1 =y^2\\bc-1 =z^2$$ then what you can instead always find is a ***fourth*** integer $d = a + b + c - 2 a b c - 2 x y z$ such that, $$1-ad = p^2\\1-bd=q^2\\1-cd=r^2$$ You can use your own example to find $d$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is a special case of the problem which is labelled *diophantine m-tuples* in the literature, or more specifically you are asking for a *diophantine quadruple with the property D(-1)*. Andrej Dujella has published numerous papers on the subject, and has a [web page here](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~duje/dtuples.html) on the subject, which puts the question into that context.

The question is still unsolved, but Dujella et. al. proves in their paper  [Effective solution of the D(-1)-quadruple conjecture](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~duje/pdf/esdmqc-aa2.pdf) that there can be only finitely many with $10^{10^{23}}$ being an upper bound on the maximum of $w, x, y , z$ in your notation.

Comment: Thanks for this link. Using Dujella's website, I managed to find a simple condition for rational sextuples $D(1)$ in [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1690931/4781).

Comment: Yes, Dujella's paper on the infinitude of diophantine sextuples. I read that paper in detail this summer when it was posted on arxiv. The ever so interesting link between elliptic curves and diophantine equations.

Comment: I just asked in this [MO post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/233367/generalizing-a-pattern-for-the-diophantine-m-tuples-problem) if a certain pattern can be generalized to rational $7$-tuples.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think this is possible; I think that two out of four numbers must be even, so that their product is a multiple of $4$ and not one larger than a square.....

Friday: after looking at the articles by Dujella recommended in the accepted answer, it turns out, to get a quadruple, one of the elements must be exactly $1.$ This means that we want $A,B,C$ each a square plus one, and each pairwise product also a square plus one. So I ran a simple program to do that, the numbers $A,B$ both squares plus one, then find all $C$ up to a large bound and see what happens. There is some unpredictable stuff, but the majority of triples come in  infinite families,
$$ A = t^2 + 1, \; \; B = (t+1)^2 + 1, \; \;  C = (2t+1)^2 + 4,  $$
$$ A = t^2 + 1, \; \; B = 4 t^4 + 1, \; \;  C = 16 t^8 - 4 t^4 + 1,  $$
$$ A = t^2 + 1, \; \; B = 4 t^4 + 1, \; \;  C = 4 t^4 - 4 t^3 + t^2 - 2t + 2,  $$
$$ A = t^2 + 1, \; \; B = 4 t^4 + 1, \; \;  C = 4 t^4 + 4 t^3 + t^2 + 2t + 2.  $$
The first triple comes very close, $4$ instead of $1.$ The $C$ value in the second triple cannot be a square plus one either. So, as usual, it comes down to the unpredictable triples.

Here is something similar that combines polynomials with a Pell type equation: Take $t$ from the sequence $3, 11, 41, 153, 571, 2131, \ldots$ so that $t_{k+2} = 4 t_{k+1} - t_k,$ with the result that we get an integer $w$ with  $w = \sqrt{3t^2 - 2}.$ Then let 
$$ m = -t + w, \; \; \; n = t + w, $$
with the result that $m,n$ are consecutive terms in the sequence
$$ 2, 8, 30, 112, 418, 1560, 5822, 21728, $$
which follow the same linear recursion as $t_k.$

Finally
$$ A = m^2 + 1, \; \; B = n^2 + 1, \; \; C = 4 t^2 - 2,  $$
$$ A = m^2 + 1, \; \; B = n^2 + 1, \; \; C = 12 t^2 - 2,  $$
$$ A = m^2 + 1, \; \; B = n^2 + 1, \; \; C = 48 t^4 + 16 t^2 + 1.  $$

Let me prove it with the first two numbers being $5$ and $13,$ with $5 \cdot 13 = 65 = 8^2 + 1.$ We can see that taking the third number to be $2$ works. However, what can we say about $C$ when $5C = V^2 + 1$ and $13C = W^2 + 1.$ Well,
$$ 65C = 13 V^2 + 13 = 5W^2 + 5, $$
$$  5W^2 - 13V^2 = 8. $$
The base solutions with positive entries are
$$ W = 5, \; \; V = 3,  $$
$$ W = 21, \; \; V = 13.  $$
All other solutions are derived from these by negating either $W$ or $V$ and using the transformation
$$ (W,V) \mapsto (129W + 208V, 80W + 129V). $$ The inverse of the transformation is just
$$ (W,V) \mapsto (129W - 208V, -80W + 129V). $$
That is, all solutions have both $W,V$ **odd**. Therefore $V^2 + 1$ is even and so is $C.$

I suspect there is a simple algebraic number theory proof of this that works for any initial pair of odd numbers $A,B$ with $AB = U^2 + 1.$ Gaussian Integers or something.

Genaeral shape of it: given two positive odd numbers $A,B$ with $AB = U^2 + 1,$ it is true that we can write
$$  A = \alpha^2 + \beta^2, \; \; \; B = \gamma^2 + \delta^2, $$ with
$$
\det
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
\alpha & \beta \\
\gamma & \delta
\end{array}
\right) \; = \; 1
$$
I already believe that all possible values of the third number $C$ can be expressed as
$$ C = (-\alpha + \gamma)^2 +  (-\beta + \delta)^2 = A + B - 2 \alpha \gamma - 2 \beta \delta$$
which is even. I say all possibilities because, when $A$ and $B$ have many distinct prime factors, there will be many possible ways to choose $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta,$ so I would expect several different $C.$ However, when $A,B$ are odd, $A+B$ is even and so is any value of $C.$ Needs a careful proof, I do not yet see the whole thing.

EXAMPLE: $A=65,$ $B = 901.$
The only matrix that works is
$$
\det
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
7 & 4 \\
26 & 15
\end{array}
\right) \; = \; 1
$$
$$
\det
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
7 & 4 \\
19 & 11
\end{array}
\right) \; = \; 1
$$
$$
\det
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
26 & 15 \\
19 & 11
\end{array}
\right) \; = \; 1
$$
and $C= 19^2 + 11^2 = 482$

SMALL STEPS  Wednesday 9 March: with $AB=U^2 + 1,$ once $A,B > 1$ and $A \neq B,$ the recipe above will always give
$$ C = A+B-2U. $$
Perhaps there really is only one value of $C?$ If so, the answer to the OP is a simple no.

Comment: We have to put the constraint that ***two*** of the integers are $\neq 1$, otherwise $1,1,10,17$ is a solution.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII, sure, I was assuming distinctness.. I think I was assuming no numbers were $1.$ Just did first experiment, while there are two ways each to write $65$ and $901$ as the sum of two squares, there is essentially just one way to choose my $\alpha, \beta,\gamma, \delta.$ So maybe there is only one $C$ value under all your restrictions on the odd pair $A,B$

Comment: Can you look at this [MO post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/233367/generalizing-a-pattern-for-the-diophantine-m-tuples-problem) if you have some ideas for the $m=5$ case? Thanks.

Comment: This [MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/88929/a-family-of-pellian-equations) is related to D(-1) case (after we know that any D(-1)-quadruple contains element 1)

Comment: @duje thank you, I had not noticed that one. How far were you able to check on computer, looking for $D(-1)$ quadruple containing a $1?$ I have been playing with it, but it is just my home computer. I did download two of your articles about this, perhaps you give information about numerical experiments there.

Comment: In N. C. Bonciocat, M. Cipu, M. Mignotte, On D(-1)-quadruples, Publ. Mat. 56 (2012), 279-304, it was proved that if {1,b,c,d} is a D(-1)-quadruple, then b>10^{13}.

Comment: @duje thanks. I looked at your MO question, Franz mentions some of the infinite families I put here. We can get near so easily: $b = t^2 + 1,$ $c = (t+1)^2 + 1,$ $d = (2t+1)^2 + 4,$ where the pairwise products are each one larger that a square.

Comment: And by T. S. Trudgian, Bounds on the number of Diophantine quintuples, J. Number Theory 157 (2015), 233-249. there are at most 3.01 * 10^60 D(-1)-quadruples.

Comment: @WillJagy These papers are relevant for the conjecture from my MO question: https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/glasnik/vol_48/no2_04.html https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/glasnik/vol_50/no2_01.html

Answer (score 2):

Nicolae Ciprian Bonciocat, Mihai Cipu, and Maurice Mignotte, There is no Diophantine $D(-1)$-quadruple, Journal of the London Mathematical Society, Volume 105, Issue 1, January 2022, Pages 63-99, https://doi.org/10.1112/jlms.12507 prove that there are no four distinct positive integers such that each pair has product one more than a square. Here is the abstract:

A set of positive integers with the property that the product of any two of them is the successor of a perfect square is called Diophantine $D(-1)$-set. Such objects are usually studied via a system of generalized Pell equations naturally attached to the set under scrutiny. In this paper, an innovative technique is introduced in the study of Diophantine $D(-1)$-quadruples. The main novelty is the uncovering of a quadratic equation relating various parameters describing a hypothetical $D(-1)$-quadruple with integer entries. In combination with extensive computations, this idea leads to the confirmation of the conjecture according to which there is no Diophantine $D(-1)$-quadruples.

Currently, access at https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1112/jlms.12507 requires payment or institutional subscription. A version is freely available on arXiv at https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.09200