# Quadruples of integers $(a,b,c,d)$ such that for any two distinct elements, $n,m$, $nm+1$ is a square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

Find quadruples of positive non-zero integers $(a, b, c, d)$, such that all pairwise products of the four numbers plus one are square numbers. Consider $1 \leq a < b < c < d < N$. How many quadruples exist if $N = 100000$?

Using a brute force approach, for $N = 1000$, I find three solutions: $(1, 3, 8, 120)$, $(1, 8, 15, 528)$ and $(2, 4, 12, 420)$. For the third quadruple:

- $2 \cdot 4 + 1 = 3 \cdot 3$
- $2 \cdot 12 + 1 = 5 \cdot 5$
- $2 \cdot 420 + 1 = 29 \cdot 29$
- $4 \cdot 12 + 1 = 7 \cdot 7$
- $4 \cdot 420 + 1 = 41 \cdot 41$
- $12 \cdot 420 + 1 = 71 \cdot 71$

I assume there is no simple answer for this, but is it solvable at all? Can it be connected with existing problems with known/unknown solutions?

Comment: From your statement of "Consider $1 < a < b < c < d < N$", it seems you're excluding $1$ as one of the possible values. If so, please make it explicit that you're only allowing integers $\gt 1$.

Comment: Let me just include 1 as well as it does not really matter (two more solutions).

Comment: Thanks for the update. There's also a typo in that $4 \times 12 + 1 = 49 = 7 \times 7$, but you have it being $5 \times 5$ instead.

Comment: $(6,400,504,620)$ is not a solution, $\sqrt{400\cdot 620 + 1}=497.997$.

Comment: Yes, thanks @orion . There was a stupid problem with integer overflow in my brute force solution.

Comment: This is a well-known, classic problem in Number Theory. A search term is "diophantine quadruples" or "diophantine 4-tuples" or "diophantine $n$-tuples". Maybe start with https://www.math.ubc.ca/~gerg/slides/Hanover-6May10a.pdf

Comment: Thanks for this term! It's really hard to find such a term without knowing about it. Will go through the answers and the slides later the day.

Comment: Any thoughts on the answers that have been posted, overseas?

Comment: Yes, I need some more time. I am currently reading through the links. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: I voted up the one answer quoting and hinting to the name of this problem. But also the other hints where very helpful and gave me first insights! Very interesting problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Greg Martin [shows](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~gerg/slides/Hanover-6May10a.pdf) that the number of such quadruples up to $N$ is asymptotic to $CN^{1/3}\log N$, where $C={2^{4/3}\over3\Gamma(2/3)^3}$, which is about $0.33828$.

Comment: Journal reference: G. Martin and S. Sitar, Erdos-Turan with a moving target, equidistribution of roots of reducible quadratics, and Diophantine quadruples, Mathematika 57 (2011), 1–29. On arXiv at https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.1834

Comment: Note also an earlier question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688687/find-integers-w-x-y-z-such-that-the-product-of-each-two-of-them-minus-1-i about diophantine quadruples.

Comment: Main contrubution comes from the quadruples of the form {a, b, a+b+2r, 4r(a+r)(b+r)}, where ab+1=r^2 (this formula for quadruples was known already to Euler).

Comment: Links to other related stackexchange and mathoverflow questions can be found at https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~duje/ddlinks.html

Answer (score 4):

From John Omielan's answer, we see that we are looking for a number $P=abcd$ that can be expressed as the product of two numbers of the form $k^2-1$ in three different ways.

Note that $P\le N(N-1)(N-2)(N-3)$, so bounding $N$ or $P$ doesn't make much difference.

You can start looking for numbers of the form $P=(r^2-1)(s^2-1)<N^4$. This has a cost $O(N^2/2)$, which it is fair better than brute force. Then look for numbers of the form $k^2-1$ which divide $P$. You needn't look for divisors greater that $\sqrt P$, so it has a cost $O(\sqrt[4]P)=O(N)$. Total cost is then $O(N^3/2)$.

If you find two more divisors of $P$ $d_1$ and $d_2$ of the form $k^2-1$, just check if $P/d_1$ and $P/d_2$ are also of this form.

To find $a,b,c,d$, we assume that we already have the six divisors $d_1<d_2<\ldots<d_6$.

Now, $d_1=ab$, $d_2=ac$. Then $d_1/d_2=b/c$, but $bc=d_3$, so 
$$b=\sqrt{\frac{d_1d_3}{d_2}}$$
Now, from $d_1=ab$ you get $a$, etc.

Answer (score 3):

This is only a partial answer, but I believe it might help provide you with a direction to pursue to check on this further. Your requirement of each pairwise products plus $1$ to be perfect squares leads to the following set of equations

$$ab + 1 = s_1^2 \iff ab = s_1^2 - 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

$$ac + 1 = s_2^2 \iff ac = s_2^2 - 1 \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

$$ad + 1 = s_3^2 \iff ad = s_3^2 - 1 \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

$$bc + 1 = s_4^2 \iff bc = s_4^2 - 1 \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

$$bd + 1 = s_5^2 \iff bd = s_5^2 - 1 \tag{5}\label{eq5}$$

$$cd + 1 = s_6^2 \iff cd = s_6^2 - 1 \tag{6}\label{eq6}$$

Next, \eqref{eq1} times \eqref{eq6} gives

$$abcd = (s_1^2 - 1)(s_6^2 - 1) \tag{7}\label{eq7}$$

Also, \eqref{eq2} times \eqref{eq5} gives

$$abcd = (s_2^2 - 1)(s_5^2 - 1) \tag{8}\label{eq8}$$

In addition, \eqref{eq3} times \eqref{eq4} gives

$$abcd = (s_3^2 - 1)(s_4^2 - 1) \tag{9}\label{eq9}$$

Combining \eqref{eq7}, \eqref{eq8} and \eqref{eq9} gives

$$abcd = (s_1^2 - 1)(s_6^2 - 1) = (s_2^2 - 1)(s_5^2 - 1) = (s_3^2 - 1)(s_4^2 - 1) \tag{10}\label{eq10}$$

Thus, you're basically looking for $3$ cases where the product of two distinct squares $- 1$ are equal to each other. I did some checking of this issue myself, and also a few brief online searches (note I had some difficulty determining what the most appropriate search terms to use are), but I wasn't able to find anything more about research, if any, which has done into under what types of conditions, and what sorts of limitations (e.g., are there an infinite number of such values), to have this occurrence of even $2$ of these products, much less $3$ of them, equaling each other occur.

Comment: If you factorize the differences of squares, we are looking for a product of 4 numbers that can be rearranged into product into 4 other numbers in 3 more distinct ways (where pairs of factors must always differ by two), which puts a lower limit on the number of factors in abcd. Some of the $s_i-1$ and $s_i+1$ may overlap (look at 3,5,7 sequence in the example), but not all of them can. I think it can be shown that 4 is the upper limit (maybe it's even 3), so $abcd$ must have at least 9 distinct factors (possibly including 1, if $s_1=2$).