# Diophantine D(12)-quadruple

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

By Diophantine $D(12)$-quadruple I mean the set $\{a,b,c,d\}$ of positive integers in which the product of any 2 distinct elements plus 12 is a perfect square in $\mathbb{N}.$

I am trying to prove that every element of the Diophantine $D(12)$-quadruple is even.

I was trying to look at the equations $xy+12=z^2$, where $x,y\in\{a,b,c,d\}$ modulo $4, 8, 16$, but all I managed to prove is that at most $2$ elements are odd, which means nothing for me.

Comment: Are $a,b,c,d$ positive integers, or just integers? See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3313909/quadruples-of-integers-a-b-c-d-such-that-for-any-two-distinct-elements-n-m).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I saw the post, but unfortunately it doesn't help in this situation. Also, they are positive integers.

Comment: Perhaps dr. Dujella can tell us something more about it? @duje

Comment: @Aqua See the answer below. Let me mention that it is not know is there any $D(12)$-quaduple consisting of four distinct integers. If we allow two equal elements in a quadruple, then there are infinitely many such quadruples, e.g. $\{2,2,12,26\}$, $\{2,2,26,44\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found in this paper 
https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~duje/pdf/acta1.pdf

Let $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}$ be a $D(12)$-quadruple. 
Assume that one if its elements, say $a_1$, is odd. 
It is easy to see that the square of an integer
is congruent to $0, 1, 4$ or $9 \pmod{16}$. 
Therefore, $a_i a_j \equiv 4, 5, 8$ or $13 \pmod{16}$, for
$i, j = 1, 2, 3, 4$, $i \neq j$. This implies that if some $a_i$ is even, then it is
divisible by $4$. Since $a_ia_j$ is not divisible by $16$, we conclude that there
must be at most one even number, i.e. at least three odd numbers, among
$a_i$, $i = 1, 2, 3, 4$.

Let $a_1, a_2, a_3 $ be odd. We have $a_1a_2 \equiv 5 \pmod{8}$, $a_1a_3 \equiv 5 \pmod{8}$, $a_2a_3 \equiv 5 \pmod{8}$. 
By multiplying these congruences, we obtain
$(a_1a_2a_3)^2 \equiv 5^3 = 125 \equiv 5 \pmod{8}$,
which is impossible, since the square of an integer is congruent to $0, 1$ or $4$ mod $8$.

Answer (score 0):

Idea:

Say $D(12)=\{1,4,13,d\}$ then $$13d+12= n^2\implies n = 13k\pm 5$$

so $$d= 13k^2\pm10k +1$$

Now try to find if for some $k$ you can have also $$4d+12 = m^2\;\;\;\wedge \;\;\; d+12=s^2$$

Comment: This was no help to you?